# DRCSIM: Which ROS versions will be supported?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The current drcsim uses ROS Fuerte for the controllers and basic interfaces, but uses the standalone Gazebo system.

The anticipated release of ROS Groovy has major changes to the representations and build systems, while Fuerte does not have all of the new updated packages.

Which versions will be supported in drcsim going forward?
What is the timetable for Groovy support if applicable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/246/drcsim:-which-ros-versions-will-be-supported?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-01-07**:
Seconding this question, now that groovy is out it becomes even more important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For the foreseeable future, we'll be developing with and releasing against Fuerte.  We know it better, it's been out longer, and as a result is less likely to yield surprises.  If I had to guess now, I would say that we'll be using Fuerte for the VRC this summer.

In parallel, we'll start evaluating Groovy.  It would help us if folks who are motivated to use Groovy with drcsim could start trying it out themselves.  The [source installation instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install#Ubuntu_Linux_2) would be a good starting point.  If everything can be built against Groovy, we could start spinning experimental binary .debs that build against Groovy.

Note that, even if gazebo and/or drcsim are built against Fuerte for use in the VRC, teams could very likely use Groovy in their own software, on both the team code machine and on their other non-cloud-hosted computing resources.  As long as the ROS API exposed by the simulation machine isn't too exotic, the Fuerte-based simulation machine should happily interact with teams' Groovy software over the wire.

That would be another thing for motivated folks to try out: run drcsim as we've released it (using Fuerte), then interact with it from Groovy-based ROS nodes.  The more that people know about possible hiccups with that setup, the better.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0